# Trouble with JSON (Data.Aeson)

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I'm new to Haskell and in order to learn the language I am working on a project that involves dealing with JSON. I am currently getting the feeling Haskell is the wrong language for the job, but that isn't the point here.

I've been struggling to understand how this works for a few days. I have searched and everything I have found does not seem to work. Here's the issue:

I have some JSON in the following format:

```
>>>less "path/to/json"
{
"stringA1_stringA2": {"stringA1":floatA1,
                      "stringA2":foatA2},
"stringB1_stringB2": {"stringB1":floatB1,
                      "stringB2":floatB2}
...
}
```

Here floatX1 and floatX2 are actually strings of the form "0.535613567", "1.221362183" etc. What I want to do is parse this into the following data

```
data Mydat = Mydat { name :: String, num :: Float} deriving (Show)
```

where name would correspond to "stringX1_stringX2" and num to floatX1 for X = A,B,...

So far I have reached a 'solution' which feels fairly hackish and convoluted and doesn't work properly.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import Data.Functor
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Aeson
import Data.List
import Data.Text
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as DHM
--import qualified Data.HashMap as DHM
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LBS
import System.Environment
import GHC.Generics
import Text.Read

data Mydat = Mydat {name :: String, num :: Float} deriving (Show)

test s = do 
  d <- LBS.readFile s 
  let v = decode d :: Maybe (DHM.HashMap String Object) 
  case v of
    -- Just v -> print v
    Just v -> return $ Prelude.map dataFromList $ DHM.toList $ DHM.map (DHM.lookup "StringA1") v


good = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','.']

f x = elem x good

dataFromList :: (String, Maybe Value) -> Mydat
dataFromList (a,b) = Mydat a (read (Prelude.filter f (show b)) :: Float)
```

Now I can compile this and run

```
test "path/to/json"
```

in ghci and it prints a list of Mydat's in the case where "stringX1"="stringA1" for all X. In reality there are two values for "stringX1" so aside from the hackyness this is not satisfactory. There must be a better way to do this. I get that I need to write my own parser probably but I am confused about how this works so any suggestions would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want to define your own `FromJSON` instance here. If you want an example of how to do that you should really provide a sample of `"path/to/json"`

Comment: Its there at the beginning, I'll edit to make it clearer.

Comment: `"stringA1":floatA1` isn't valid json. Presumably this should be `"stringA1":0.0` or something?

Comment: Sorry, yes should have made this clear too, floatX1 are actually strings like "0.238238273827" but it should really end up being a floats in the end.

Comment: Why do you have them as _strings_ in the JSON file? why not `"stringA1": 0.238238273827`?

Comment: The JSON arrives from an external source... So I'm not in control of that unfortunately. I know I could process it in python first but that defeats the point of learning something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of your JSON is pretty nasty, but here's a basic working solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-11.5 script --package containers --package aeson
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Data.Aeson as Aeson

data Mydat = Mydat { name :: String
                   , num  :: Float
                   } deriving (Show)


instance Eq Mydat where
    (Mydat _ x1) == (Mydat _ x2) = x1 == x2

instance Ord Mydat where
    (Mydat _ x1) `compare` (Mydat _ x2) = x1 `compare` x2

type MydatRaw = Map.Map String (Map.Map String String)

processRaw :: MydatRaw -> [Mydat]
processRaw = Map.foldrWithKey go []
    where go key value accum = 
              accum ++ (Mydat key . read <$> Map.elems value)

main :: IO ()
main =
    do let json = "{\"stringA1_stringA2\":{\"stringA1\":\"0.1\",\"stringA2\":\"0.2\"}}"
       print $ fmap processRaw (Aeson.eitherDecode json)
```

Note that `read` is partial and generally not a good idea. But I'll leave it to you to flesh out a safer version :)

Comment: Thanks allot, this almost does what I want and I think I'll be able to modify it to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, the best thing would probably be to make your JSON file well-formed in the sense that the float fields should really be floats, not strings.

If that's not an option, I would recommend you phrase out the type that the JSON file *seems to represent* as simple as possible (but without dynamic `Object`s), and then convert that to the type you actually want.

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

type GarbledJSON = Map String (Map String String)
                -- ^ you could also stick with hash maps for everything, but
                --   usually `Map` is actually more sensible in Haskell.

data MyDat = MyDat {name :: String, num :: Float} deriving (Show)

test :: FilePath -> IO [MyDat]
test s = do 
  d <- LBS.readFile s 
  case decode d :: Maybe GarbledJSON of
    Just v -> return [ MyDat iName ( read . filter (`elem`good)
                                             $ iVals Map.! valKey )
                     | (iName, iVals) <- Map.toList v
                     , let valKey = takeWhile (/='_') iName ]
```

Note that this will crash completely if any of the items don't contain the first part of the name as a string of float format, and likely give bogus items when you filter out characters that aren't `good`. If you just want to ignore any malformed items (which is also not a very clean approach...), you can do it this way:

```
test :: FilePath -> IO [MyDat]
test s = do 
  d <- LBS.readFile s 
  return $ case decode d :: Maybe GarbledJSON of
    Just v -> [ MyDat iName iVal
              | (iName, iVals) <- Map.toList v
              , let valKey = takeWhile (/='_') iName
              , Just iValStr <- [iVals Map.!? valKey]
              , [(iVal,"")] <- [reads iValStr] ]
    Nothing -> []
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately I both of these didn't want to compile..  "Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘[]’
      Expected type: [LBS.ByteString]
        Actual type: IO LBS.ByteString" seems to be the key part of the error message. But I will accept Jordan's solution below since it nearly works and I think I can understand it. Thanks again for your quick response!

Comment: Of course it must be `IO [MyDat]` in the type signature because you're reading from a file. (Though it would actually better to make the conversion `GarbledJSON -> [MyDat]` a separate, pure function.)